# Adding Dynamic States to React JS project

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am creating an [emojipedia](https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-panini-xwy1n) app where it is expected to open a [Modal](https://mui.com/components/modal/), which contains the description of the emoji, when an emoji is pressed. As far as I know, to do so, I need to map the description(contained in `emojipedia.js` file) of the emoji to the `EmojiContainer` component in `Components` folder.

Here comes my problem where when I press a emoji, it is getting hanged. Why is this happening and how to fix this???

THANKS IN ADVANCE.

Comment: Hello.

If you want some help, you need to at least provide some sample code.

Comment: I have provided the codesand box link there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a single state on `EmojiContainer` to control all modals in your emoji list. As a consequence, when you try and open a modal, all modals open. A better option would be to encapsulate all logic relative to a single modal in a separate, reusable component:

```
export default function Emoji({ item }) {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  return (
    <Grid item lg={2} md={3} xs={6}>
      <ImageButton onClick={() => setOpen(true)}>
        <CardMedia
          sx={{
            "&:hover": {
              transform: "scale(1.3)"
            }
          }}
          component="img"
          height="100"
          image={item.link}
          alt="emoji"
        />
      </ImageButton>
      <Modal
        open={open}
        onClose={() => setOpen(false)}
        aria-labelledby="modal-modal-title"
        aria-describedby="modal-modal-description"
      >
        <Typography sx={style} variant="p">
          {item.desc}
        </Typography>
      </Modal>
    </Grid>
  );
}
```

As you see this component has its own state and controls its own modal. In your EmojiContainer you can use it like this:

```
export default function EmojiContainer() {
  return (
    <Grid>
      {emojipedia.map((item, index) => (
        <Grid key={index} container>
          <Emoji item={item} />
        </Grid>
      ))}
    </Grid>
  );
}
```

From what I see you'll also need to adjust the modal styling. Here's the updated [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-https-45g3p)